# Share PHP session between multiple web applications

Tags: php, session

I have two web applications on the same domain (a CMS and an E-Commerce platform) and I would like to share session data between them.  I can easily set it up so they both use the same session, but there is too much potential for variable name collisions in the $_SESSION variable.  I thought I could use named sessions, but I couldn't get it to work either:

```
session_name("WEB_APP_ONE");
session_start();
$webAppOneData = $_SESSION;
session_write_close();

//var_dump($_SESSION) = all of the session data for web app one is still contained in $_SESSION even though I closed the session with session_write_close()

session_name("WEB_APP_TWO");
session_start();
$_SESSION['WEB_APP_ONE'] = $webAppOneData;

//var_dump($_SESSION) = all of the session data for web app one is still here
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to know if it is!

Note: the actual use-case I'm getting at is being able to show how many products are in the visitor's cart in the CMS.  The cart data is stored in the e-commerce platform's session, but I need to show from the header of the CMS.  I want there to be seamless integration between the CMS and shopping cart.

Comment: Have you considered using cookies?

Comment: excellent question. This is surprising. I wonder how long this has behaved this way, because I've used session_name() with session_write_close() in the same script before like this, for the same reasons you want to.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45380

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just name-spacing the sessions with a nested array:

```
$_SESSION['app1']['app1var'] = 'value';
$_SESSION['app2']['app2var'] = 'value';
```

You might also consider storing and retrieving session info from a database instead, using the session only to store user auth information which tells you which database row(s) to access.